# How to remove portions of a list by self referencing keys in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a list with this type: `[(a, [a])]`.
For example:

```
[("a",["x","y"]),("x",["a","y"]),("z",[]),("y",["a","x"])]
```

I would like to filter this list. The filtering should work like this:

1. start at first item, traverse items from first tuple
2. remove keys that are in the first tuple (so remove `"x"`, `"y"`)

End result should become:

```
[("a",["x","y"]),("z",[])] -- the "x" and "y" are removed because they live in "a"
```

The idea is to get a list and then to apply `Map.delete` from `import qualified Data.Map as Map` on that list. However, I'm stuck on the things when `Maybe` is introduced. This is my code:

```
import System.IO
import Data.Maybe as Maybe
import qualified Data.Map as Map


list = [("a",["x","y"]),("x",["a","y"]),("z",[]),("y",["a","x"])]
    
main :: IO ()
main = do
    let myMap = Map.fromList list
    let myList = funcA list myMap 
    print myList
    
funcA (x:xs) myMap
   | f == Nothing = Nothing
--   | otherwise = f
--   | otherwise = funcC f myMap
   | otherwise = Maybe.maybeToList f
    where a = fst x
          f = funcB a myMap

funcB key myMap = Map.lookup key myMap

funcC portion myMap = portion
```

Can you help me out?

-------------- edit

After answering the code will look like this:

```
import System.IO
import Data.Maybe as Maybe
import qualified Data.Map as Map


list = [("a",["x","y"]),("x",["a","y"]),("z",[]),("y",["a","x"])]
    
main :: IO ()
main = do
    let myList = removeKeys list
    print myList


removeKeys :: Eq a => [(a, [a])] -> [(a, [a])]
removeKeys [] = []
removeKeys (kv@(_, vs): kvs) = kv : removeKeys (filter ((`notElem` vs). fst) kvs)
```

Output:

```
> runghc program
[("a",["x","y"]),("z",[])]
```

I like the answered solution because of the creative way `filter` was used. It is basically doing this:

```
Prelude> let vs = ["x","y"]
Prelude> let kvs = [("x",["a","y"]),("z",[]),("y",["a","x"])]
Prelude> filter ((`notElem` vs). fst) kvs
[("z",[])]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a recursive function that filters the rest of the list with the items in the second item of the 2-tuples, so:

```
removeKeys :: Eq a => [(a, [a])] -> [(a, [a])]
removeKeys [] = []
removeKeys (kv@(_, vs): kvs) = kv : removeKeys (filter ((`notElem` vs). fst) kvs)
```

The items in the values that are in the key-value pairs of removed items will not be considered. So if `"x"` for example had `("x", ["a", "y", "z"])`, it will not remove `"z"`, since it was in an item that was already removed.

Comment: Yeah, that works! I like your approach; the `(kv@(_, vs): kvs)` pattern is a beautiful tool for this problem.

Comment: I like this part as well: `filter ((\`notElem\` vs). fst) kvs`